# Why does Flutter's WillPopScope always block going back?

Tags: ios, flutter

Whenever I've tried to block the ability to swipe back with Flutter on iOS I've tried using `WillPopScope`. However, regardless of what value I put in `onWillPop:` it will always block the ability to swipe back.

Why is this? It doesn't matter if `onWillPop` returns true or false, it always blocks.

```
    final isConfirmation = _isConfirmation();
    WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: _appBar(),
        body: _body(),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async => isConfirmation,
    );
```

This issue happens even if I return a hard `true` or `false`

`onWillPop: () async => true`

`onWillPop: () async => false`

`onWillPop: () => Future<bool>.value(true)`

`onWillPop: () => Future<bool>.value(false)`

Comment: share `_isConfirmation()` code.

Comment: Could you please make a simple reproducible code? Just a simple project with two pages and `WillPopScope` on the second returning true or false. If that still doesn't work, maybe it's a bug and you can report it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this.

##### if `_isConfirmation()` is a `Future` method, use `await` before it in the code below.

```
onWillPop: () async {
  final bool confirmation = _isConfirmation();  // use await if it is future.
  return Future<bool>.value(confirmation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was missing the `async` when I tried with Future

Comment: Glad i was able to help.